# What do you call a person who goes home early?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to use this word for describing a man who doesn't have the habit of stretching his time.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, please add an example sentence in which you want to use the word you are looking for.

Comment: Is he shrinking his time or just not stretching it?

Comment: I mean he is just not stretching it. Basically, he wants to stick to the stipulated time.

Comment: From what location is he going home early? Work? Church? The ball game? School? A party? This person sounds like a "home body" to me!

Comment: A person who works at an office.

Comment: Your title question and body question do not correspond. Someone who requires people to work unpaid extra time is the person at fault, not the person choosing to invest their free time in other pursuits.

Answer (score 1):

If he wants to stick to the stipulated time, he would be a clock-watcher.